# Unit testing Chef definition: undefined method `definitions' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, chef-infra

I am writing a cookbook, and of course I need to unit test it.
This cookbook doesn't really have any recipes however provides definitions.

I decided to use the programmatic method of creating recipes for unit testing the definitions but I keep stumbling into the error:

```
undefined method `definitions' for nil:NilClass
```

Here is the current code:

```
describe '#nginx_site (definition)' do
  def fake_recipe(run, &block)
    recipe = Chef::Recipe.new('nginxsite', 'mockrecipe', run.run_context)
    recipe.instance_eval(&block)
  end

  let :chef_run do
    ChefSpec::SoloRunner.new(platform: 'ubuntu', version: '14.04')
  end

  it 'should do some magic' do
    recipe = fake_recipe(chef_run) do
      nginx_site 'foo' do
        enable true
      end
    end

    chef_run.converge(recipe)
  end
end
```

Comment: @Tensibai because in my eyes, and in a few blog posts I have read, it is cleaner to do it like this. Making your test fully configurable and isolated.

Comment: Anyway, add a `log_level: :debug` in your SoloRunner before the platform attribute to have a more detailed view of what's going wrong. I would say it cost nothing to make a test recipe to ensure chefspec is working properly before moving to this method.

Comment: @Tensibai I will give it a whirl and see what happens. I too will delete my statement. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Any update on the tests ? (Maybe you may answer yourself the question if you found the culprit)